# Code issue about rendering the web frames with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, render

Definitely a beginner question... basically, I want to have the same design from this website. I understand the HTML part, but the problem is that I am not completely sure how to actually render multiple html files in one view.

http://www.htmliseasy.com/frames_tutor/templates/template1.html

My webpage is in this linkk. http://everyology.appspot.com/biology

What I am using is Google app engine. Here is a partial code that is relevant to the question. My concern is with class BioPage... I wrote these and am seeing the frames but getting 404 errors in my webpage.

```
import os
import webapp2
from string import letters

import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           autoescape = True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')

class BioPage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('biology.html') 
        self.render('doc1.html')
        self.render('doc2.html')
```

Comment: Actually, I've solved it by using Dropbox and putting HTML files there and then using those files in frame src. But I am still interested in learning how to render the files through Python.

Comment: You solved the problem by accident. By putting the files onto dropbox, the browser is making one request for each, bypassing the code you have the tries to render all at once. I've explained it a bit more below.

Comment: Why do you want to use frames at all? Are you sure you shouldn't just be rendering all the content as part of one larger page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running in to is how `<frame>` tags operate. To fill in frames, browsers make an additional request *per frame*. Your code is trying to guess ahead, shipping all of the frame contents back in one clump. That's not how it works. You're going to need separate handlers for each of your frames, in addition to the main page. Alternatively, those pages that are completely static can be served static pages.